# How to make my ruby script shippable

Tags: ruby, deployment, bundler

I want to ship a ruby script and not ask the end consumer to run gem install or some bundler command. I just wants him to open the zip and run my script.

I understand that I will need to bundle my gems inside my zip but I am not sure how it can be achieved.

Today I am using bundler with the following .bundle/config:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: lib/vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
```

and I do some nasty manipulation on library search path, in the beginning of my script:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/colored-1.2/lib"
```

To conclude, What is the **right way** to create a statically linked (without external dependencies) ruby shippable script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You might want to look at `bundle install --standalone`, which generates a file that does all of the necessary load path manipulation.

http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/03/faster-test-boot-times-with-bundler-standalone